# How to include a cell data into a text string?

Tags: join, google-sheets, concatenation, google-sheets-formula, textjoin

I'm sure there is this information out there, but I can't seem to find it likely due to ill searching.

I'm looking to include data from a cell

```
Blah Blah Bah

with blah {C3} should be blah blah blah

and some more Blah Blah Blah
```

I want to have a text string and include the data from C3.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the exact of your example would be:

```
="Blah Blah Bah"&CHAR(10)&
 "with blah "&C3&" should be blah blah blah"&CHAR(10)&
 "and some more Blah Blah Blah"
```

[image: 0]

Answer (score 1):

This would be done through `TEXTJOIN()`

For example:

```
=TEXTJOIN(" ",TRUE,"Blah Blah Bah",C1,"more Blah Blah Blah")
```

You could also reference other cells instead of typing your textstring into the formula:

```
=TEXTJOIN(" ",TRUE,A1,C1,A2)
```

You can also opt for the more 'simpler' approuch to emulate a concatenate through:

```
="Blah Blah Bah "&C1&" more Blah Blah Blah"
```

Or even with cell references (including spaces at end and beginning)

```
=A1&C1&A2
```

It's mindblowing to think you haven't been able to find this online....